# mongodb find documents using condition and update another field in the respective document

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, loops, mongodb-query

I want to find any document in my collection that:

- its **hobby** field is empty
- or its **hobby** field doesn't exist

and then set the value of its **hobby** field to be equivalent of its **sports** field.

```
 db.myCollection.update(
            { $or: [{"hobby": {$exists: false} },{"hobby": ""}]}
        , {
            $set: {
                hobby: ????sports
            }
        }, {
            multi: true
        },
        function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            console.log(err);
        })
```

With this command above, I suppose I will be passing the value of **sports** as fixed value to all matching documents. is there any way to pick up its corresponding **sports** value and set it to **hobby**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in 2 queries:

```
db.myCollection.find({ 
  $or: [{ "hobby": { $exists: false } }, { "hobby": "" }]
}).toArray().forEach(function (item) {
    db.myCollection.update(
      { _id: item._id },
      { $set: { hobby: item.sports } },
      { multi: true }
    )
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the modified version that updates correctly the values:

```
   db.myCollection.find({ 
      $or: [{ "hobby": { $exists: false } }, { "hobby": "" }]
    }).toArray().forEach(function (item) {
        db.myCollection.update(
          { _id: item._id },
          { $set: { hobby: item.sports } },
          { multi: true }
        )
      })
    })
```